# how to gather logs in django with aws autoscaling (ecs or beanstalk or simple autoscaling)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, logging, autoscaling

Im wondering if there is a feature in aws to gather logs of application such as django when autoscaling is enabled?

Do I need to do it manually with bashscript and a storage or is it available in aws monitoring tools?

Thanks a lot.

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS solution is to send your logs to [CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html).